# Question on Mothur classify.seqs : Sequence not found in taxonomy file

Tags: taxonomy, mothur

Hello I've been getting this issue and I'm not sure how to fix it. I'm currently running the following command on mothur:
classify.seqs(fasta=all.good.unique.good.filter.unique.abund.pick.fasta, count= all.good.unique.good.filter.abund.pick.count_table,template=cnidarian_alligned_ref.fasta, taxonomy=TaxCnida_ref.txt, cutoff=90, method=wang, processors=8)

However, I get the same error message:
AADBE121-10 is in your taxonomy file and is not in your template file. Please correct.
AADBE128-10 is in your taxonomy file and is not in your template file. Please correct.
AADBE304-10 is in your taxonomy file and is not in your template file. Please correct.
ABBAC001-10 is in your taxonomy file and is not in your template file. Please correct.
ABBAC002-10 is in your taxonomy file and is not in your template file. Please correct.

This goes on for every single entry.

I'm not sure why this happens since I've made sure that sequence names are in both files. I even copy pasted by hand to make sure.
From what I looked of similar errors such as this one, I don't seem to have any of the same character issues that other have, such as hyphons instead of underscores.
Currently using mothur v.1.48.0

I'm stuck here any type of help would be very much appreciated. If there's something I didn't make very clear, also let me know. I'm kind of new to this type of analysis and using stack overflow in general.

### Here are examples on what there is on the files
-fasta file: >AADBE121-10

---

---

---

---

---

---

---

---

---

---

---

---

---

### --------------------------------------------aaca------------

### -----------------t-t----------------------------------------

### ----------------------------------------ata-----------------
------------------t-ct--------------------------------------
--agtattt---------------------------gg----------------------
------------------------------------aa-t-aggat--------------

### ---------------ctg---------------------gtatg---------------a
ta------------------ggcacagc--------------------------------
---------------------tttaagtatg-----------------------------
-------------ttaata------------------agattgg----------------
----------------------------------aa------------------------
-----ttatctg---------------------------------------cccc-cgga
ac--------------------------------------tat-gt--------------
-------------------ta-gg-gga--------------cgatc-------------

### --------------atc-----------------------------------t-------
------------ttata----------atgtt----------------------------
---------------atagtaacg------------------------------------
----------------------------------------------------------gc
gca---------------------------------------------------------
----------------cgctt---------------------------ttgttatgatt-

### -----------ttct-------------------------------ttctagtaat----

---

### --------------------------------------------------------gcc-
-----------agtt---------------------------------------------

---

### ------------------atgatagga---------------------------------
---------------ggatttggt------------------------------------
-----------------aat----------------------------------------
-tggt-tggtc-------cctcta-t----------------------------------

### catt-ggtgcccc-----------------------------------------------
------cgat--------------------------------------------------

---

### -------------at--------ggct----------ttcc-------------------
------ctcgactaaataata---------------------------------------
----------------------------------------ttagtttttga---------
--------------------------------------ttactccctc-ccgc-------

-Taxonomy file: AADBE304-10 Cnidaria;Anthozoa;Actiniaria;;;;